# Kafka Consumer Error On Calling Rest Call

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

How to handle below error when the consumer is calling a rest template but the remote host is unavailable.

```
[kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | dirty_node] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-dirty_node-7, groupId=dirty_node] Member consumer-dirty_node-7-8fdc41f2-4a8a-41ca-9234-b6b56490d28d sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator kafka-2.qat.test.net:9093 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

error: read tcp 127.0.0.:443:: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Note: I'm not setting any poll timeout. It is default.
Should I increase the poll time or decrease the poll time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#max.poll.interval.ms),`max.poll.interval.ms` is the maximum delay between invocations of poll() when using consumer group management.

So you should increase `max.poll.interval.ms` and make it longer than your rest template's timeout.